# Can't figure out answer in this Python quiz

Tags: python

I'm taking the Python for Everybody course, and I got to a multiple pick question (meaning it could have multiple correct answers) and none of this syntax has been touched on in the course so far, so I have no idea what I'm looking at. Any help would be greatly appreciated! The question is as follows...

If the variable "data" is a Python list, how do we sort it in reverse order?

- True)
- data.sort.reverse()
- data
- data.sort(-1)
- data.sort(reverse
- sortrev(data)
- data

*It's possible that more than one of these are correct, I need to pick all the correct answers.

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please review the options you have presented. What is `"True)"`? and what is `"data.sort(reverse"`

Comment: Run these commands and see for yourself. Try to reason about them and make sure to check the python docs for seeing what the functions do.

Comment: You already did pick all the correct ones.

Comment: @quamrana Both of those seem like incorrect syntax to me having unclosed parenthesis.

Comment: Wow, that sounds like a bad question where you have to filter out syntax errors.

Comment: @NaitikMundra I've tried all of the commands and none of them work. My own logic tells me to try data.sort(reverse = True) which did actually work perfectly, this sadly, is not an option in the answers.

Comment: @KellyBundy I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean pick nothing, I've tried that too and the question is marked wrong

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming or `python` problem.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the question and the answer options?

Comment: @KellyBundy I'm new here and I think I need more rep before it will let me include a picture. However, I took a gyazo screenshot, and the link for it is here if you would like to take a look

https://gyazo.com/1544a69a0e84aa055572fd4720d55f2d

Comment: I suspected you didn't show it here correctly, but looks like it's indeed broken at that site already. None of those options are correct. What's the URL where you're doing this?

Comment: It's a quiz in the Python for Everybody course. I'm not sure it will show for you as I think you need an account? I could be wrong though, so here's the URL for the quiz if you wanna try it

https://www.py4e.com/mod/gift/?quiz=Py4Inf-10-Tuples.txt&PHPSESSID=6c85a21f5d12eae5e454fa339d152dba

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Hello. I'm very new here. Apologies if I used the wrong tag. Can you point me in the correct avenue to get help with something like this?

Comment: Yeah I can't see it, but at least it looks like the correct site, not some third party that didn't scrape it correctly. Anyway, it's broken. [This](https://github.com/ed-lau/python-for-everybody/blob/5f520b0eee73ec9e6fad0724d8589cc269400b62/wk%2010%20-%20quiz.py#L82) might be what it's supposed to show. I guess if it's possible, you could tell them about it and hope they fix it.

Comment: @KellyBundy Thank you so much. You can retake these quizzes over and over to get a perfect score so this has been driving me crazy. I have some peace of mind knowing that it's just a flawed question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the question is broken.

The correct answer is "data.sort(reverse = True)"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).